# Paging Library: skip loadInitial in PageKeyedDataSource

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-paging

According to the docs `loadInitial` is called during creation PagedList in UI thread to provide some placeholders until real data fetched to avoid show empty list to user.

Are there any way to skip `loadInitial` or return empty list?

If I return empty list with default config `loadAfter` will not be called.
I looked in few implementations but all people just duplicate their code to load data from internet in `loadInitial` and `loadAfter` which is not so good solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In your `loadInitial` method just set the retry action

```
setRetry(Action { loadInitial(params, callback) })

override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<String>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<String, Lab>) {
            setRetry(Action { loadInitial(params, callback) })

            // Set network state if you want
            networkState.postValue(Response(Response.ViewState.ERROR, null, Throwable("")))
            initialLoad.postValue(Response(Response.ViewState.ERROR, null, Throwable("")))
    }
```

`setRetry` method

```
private var retryCompletable: Completable? = null

private fun setRetry(action: Action?) {
        if (action == null) {
            this.retryCompletable = null
        } else {
            this.retryCompletable = Completable.fromAction(action)
        }
    }
```

And when you want to call `loadAfter` you have to `invalidate` the `sourceFactory`.

```
fun refresh() = sourceFactory.dataSource.value.invalidate()
```

Comment: @anber could you please tell me the issue that you are facing with this solution because I have tried this and it is working for me.

Comment: loadAfter method is not called and I have empty list

Comment: @anber did you `invalidate()` the `datasource`?
Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Yes I did, but it does not help. I created minimal sample to reproduce: https://github.com/akadatsky/pagingDemo